# External test data for JUnit with Ant and Jenkins

Tags: unit-testing, ant, junit, jenkins

A project I am working on uses JUnit for unit tests, with Jenkins to run them. Building is via Ant.

A particular test I have requires a csv file of test data - so my question is how to access this from within my test.

Currently I try to read the test data from the following path:

```
"/resources/com/(company)/(project)/(feature)/test_data.csv"
```

For test file:

```
"test/com/(company)/(project)/(feature)/test_file.java"
```

I then get the file handle like this:

```
final File file = new File(this.getClass().getResource(path).getFile());
```

The file tree is:

```
src
    com/(path)/source files
test
    com/(path)/test files
    resources
        com/(path)/resource files
```

This runs fine on my local machine (built using Eclipse), but not within Jenkins (built using Ant), since the resources are not copied - any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I have tried to add the following to build.xml:

```
<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="${bin.dir}" />
    <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="${bin.dir}">
        <fileset dir="test/resources" />
    </copy>
</target>
```

However, it is copying into the class directory (`bin/com/(path)/`), rather than the resources directory (`bin/resources/com/(path)/`). Since Eclipse uses the latter, it would be best to have them match so that the tests can be run using either method.

As an aside, is there somewhere else that it should be stored?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I solved it with:

```
<mkdir dir="${bin.dir}/resources" />
<copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="${bin.dir}/resources">
    <fileset dir="test/resources" />
</copy>
```

If you have any feedback on whether this is the right way to do all of this, then I would love to hear it!